# multisite multilingual over different directory

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I have multi-site over directories.

xx and yy are made symbolic links are linked to same Drupal directory

domain.tld/xx
domain.tld/yy

And on .htaccess it requires to have different Rewritebase

RewriteBase /xx

or

RewriteBase /yy

which is not possible.

Any other way to solve using someother  RewriteRule?

Note: It is also multilingual website

Update: It is Drupal 7.26

Answer (score 0):

I was solved this problem . May be use to you for only Multisite

Solution:

```
Give Symbolic link form mulitsite to site1
Executed that command line 
ln -s /var/www/multisite /var/www/site1

Rename example.sites.php to sites.php
// 192.168.1.99 local IP address
$sites['192.168.1.99.site1'] = 'site1';

put this line in sites.php
```

No need to use RewriteBase /xx

If you have any problem in symbolic link use this link https://superuser.com/questions/68685/chown-is-not-changing-symbolic-link

and also [How do I setup multiple sites with one database in Drupal 7 (or) Multisite Apache configuration with Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103800/how-do-i-setup-multiple-sites-with-one-database-in-drupal-7-or-multisite-apach)